# Changing color of of gameObject in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, colors

Okay so I have this code.

```
void Start () {
    gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = Color.green;
}
```

I expected my gameObject to change its color to green. I imported it as black and in the inspector it has turned to green however in the actual application it does not appear as green. I cant use `gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.green` since unity tell me its basically outdated and that I have to use the new version. This is going to be really simple but what am I missing? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: When I run the code a tab pops up in the inspector 'Sprites-Default (instance)' and if I change the selection box to Unlit > Color it works. Is there anyway of making this stick?

Comment: That should just work. Any chance of trying this with a new project and just a cube or something?

Comment: I have it on a 2D object if that changed anything

Comment: It might be a lighting issue. What shader is your material using? Unless it's one of the Unlit shaders, you need to create a light source in your scene. It will help if you specify what version of Unity you're using.

Comment: im using unity 5.1.1

Comment: I was not aware I needed to change the material of the object, however I have just created a new one and added it in and it seems to work. If anyone wants to answer the question completely I can mark the question as solved since I do not know exactly why it is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the color changes but you cant see the result because the shader in your material needs light and you don't have lights so you will always see it black so you can add a light source or change the materials shader to unlight.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to change a 2D sprite color try [`GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.green`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer.html) instead of just get "Renderer" component or try to [setColor()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetColor.html) with specular shader instead of direct attribution (you'll need a light source in scene).

Answer (score 1):

There are always two possibilities of not seeing the result of this code.

1. There's no light (a directional light or a point light) as pointed out by [user2320445](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2320445/user2320445).
2. There is a light but you haven't imported the `System.Collections` namespace, i.e., your program misses the statement `using System.Collections;` in the beginning of the code. If you want to write the code without using the `System.Collections` namespace, then you can replace the line

   ```
   gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = Color.green;
   ```

   with

   ```
   gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.green;
   ```

   This does not require you to import the **System.Collections** namespace.