# Strange behavior when setting the color for a GameObject in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i'm having this strange behavior when I set the color for a gameobject.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TestObject: MonoBehaviour
{
private Material screenMaterial;

private void Awake()
{
    screenMaterial= transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material;
    screenMaterial.SetColor("_Color", Color.yellow);
}
}
```

[image]

**The problem is the color is set to yellow correctly like 90% of the time and sometimes its just white.** I mean the only thing that comes to my mind on why this happen is that there isn't enough time for the script to get the material component and then sets its color?!

This is a brand new 2D project and there no other scripts.

**Any idea why this happen?**

Here's the project file. [Download](https://github.com/rashiddev93/TestProject). Made in unity 2019.2.18f1

Comment: Please include steps to reproduce the problem including what objects to create in the scene

Comment: Maybe white is default color and it's a timing issue when setting yellow color.

Comment: The steps are just one actually, I just press start and like 9 times outta a 10 the color is set to yellow or whatever color is want but just one time is just and yeah its default color. @Ruzihm

Comment: Yes the default color is white, and maybe its a timing issue but what is it? This is a new 2D project and this is the first script so whats going on? @bestinamir

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31595235/10634638

Comment: From the comments on some of the answers below, it sounds like you have multiple materials on your GameObject. Could you please show the hierarchy view of the GameObjects you have in your scene?

Comment: Yeah sure i just uploaded on the main question @whathm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to solve the issue and its actually very simple, Since the TestObject is made out of 2 objects the first one is the parent and the second one is the child..

**All I had to do is to change the sorting layers, so by setting the the sorting layer in the child object to 1 and the parent's to 0 FIXED THE ISSUE.**

I hope this help some of you guys.

Comment: You can accept your own answer so that anyone else with this problem can see what the solution was if they find this page in the future.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that the child is not always loaded in yet when Awake is called on this GameObject. I would try changing out Awake() for Start() and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I just tried that and its the same, I moved whats inside Awake() to Start() but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 2):

You are currently trying to set the color of the material. Instead of doing that, just change the `Color` field seen in the `SpriteRenderer` Component below.

[image]

You can use the following code to adjust the color of a sprite:

```
public class TestObject: MonoBehaviour
{
    private Material screenMaterial;

    private void Awake()
    {
        transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.yellow;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Its a good idea but this way the color is always white.

Comment: What do you mean? It should turn yellow. It stats off white but as soon as the game starts, it should turn to yellow. Let me take another look at your question now that you added the picture.

Comment: i'm telling you it does turn to yellow/green/red...etc and this happens everytime i press the play button, its just 1 time outta of 10 it DOESN'T, why? thats what i'm trying to figure out.

Comment: I have uploaded the unity package file

Answer (score 0):

try

```
transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material.color = Color.yellow;
```

The way you are setting color is like for a custom shader, setting the "_Color" property of the shader

edit try this:

```
for (var child : Transform in transform) {
    child.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material.color = Color.yellow;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, its still the same, why?

Comment: do you have two materials on the object?

Comment: Yes I do, the first one is (Body) and the second one is (Screen) which i'm getting its component in the Awake() method and its a child of the test object.

Comment: okay I edited my answer and gave something else to try

Comment: Again thank you but its still the same.

Comment: its probably because you are using a pure white sprite then, and when you multiply it by yellow its still white

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214290/discussion-between-rashid-dev-and-vasmos).

Comment: Yeah i'm using a pure white sprite, but it changes to whatever color i want like 9 times outta a 10 but and sometimes its still just white maybe its a unity glitch or something?

Comment: post a picture in the editor and include sprite renderer component in 'scene view' while game is running